# GetLastInputInfo() returns a number of milliseconds rather than ticks

Tags: c#, datetime, user32

I'm importing GetLastInputInfo() from User32.dll. In the [GetLastInputInfo() definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx), it states that it uses the tick count. However, in practice, it returns the millisecond count. This can be corrected with simple multiplication, since I don't need that level of precision, but I'm wondering if this is always the case, or if it varies.

EDIT:

This may have been poorly detailed initially. As noted below, in the context of the imported function, a tick is a millisecond. The confusion came from the fact that I was using it alongside Datetime.Now.Ticks. In this context, a tick is 100 nanoseconds.

Comment: As per the answer below, ticks ARE milliseconds in the Win32 API. If you want something closer to CPU cycles you might be looking for [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tick *is* a millisecond.

From the [documentation for GetLastInputInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx):

> plii [out] - a pointer to a `LASTINPUTINFO` structure that receives the time of the last input event.

From the [documentation for `LASTINPUTINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646272(v=vs.85).aspx):

> For more information on tick counts, see GetTickCount.

From the [documentation for GetTickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The return value is the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I had thought that a tick would have the same definition across the board - that was clearly a bad assumption.